# Is there any tool to test the functionality across various browsers and various versions

Tags: cross-browser

I wanted to test the functionality across various browsers.

Is there any tool to test the functionality across various browsers and various versions

Thanks

Comment: you probably asking how to test your website/web application on different browsers, right?

Comment: The functionality of *what*?  If you want to know about the browser, you could always check the documentation like everyone else.

Comment: "test the functionality" please be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly programming related, but;

we use http://crossbrowsertesting.com

Answer (score -1):

The acid tests might do what you want. If will test the conformance of the users browser with the various web standards (HTML, CSS etc.). Take a look at http://www.acidtests.org/ for more information.